# Angular 5 HTTPClient not returning results for RouteResolver

Tags: angular5, angular-httpclient

I have to say HttpClient Observables, subscriptions etc are pretty hard/time consuming to get right.

I have been working on a problem for a while now and tearing my hair out. I have a service that I need to be able to perform a mapping function on.

```
  loadAllSummary(organisationId: number) {
    return this.http.get('/api/aircrafts/organisations/' + organisationId)
      .pipe(
        map(data => data.forEach(datum => {
          console.log('why am i not getting here! ' + JSON.stringify(data));
          return this.mapToSummary(datum);
        }))
      );
  }
```

with the mapToSummary() method:

```
  private mapToSummary(aircraft: Aircraft): IAircraftSummary {
    const lastDate: Date = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, aircraft.workorders.map(function(e) {
      return new Date(e.date);
    })));

    return new AircraftSummary({
      lastWork: lastDate,
      rego: aircraft.registration,
      make: aircraft.make,
      model: aircraft.model,
      contact: (aircraft.owner.type.endsWith('primary')) ? aircraft.owner.principal : aircraft.operator.principal,
      phone: (aircraft.owner.type.endsWith('primary')) ? aircraft.owner.contact.phone : aircraft.operator.contact.phone
    });
  }
```

Now, I need these summaries as input data to a view, so I borrowed code from the interwebs and created this ResolverService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AircraftsResolverService implements Resolve<IAircraftSummary[]> {

  constructor(private service: AircraftService,
              private router: Router) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IAircraftSummary[]> {
    console.log('called AircraftsResolverService')
    const id = route.params['id'];
    if (isNaN(+id)) {
      console.log(`Organisation id was not a number: ${id}`);
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return Observable.of(null);
    }
    return this.service.loadAllSummary(+id)
      .map(summaries => {
        console.log(summaries)
        if (summaries) {
          return summaries;
        }
        console.log(`Summaries were not found: ${id}`);
        this.router.navigate(['/organisations/', +id]);
        return null;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Retrieval error: ${error}`);
        this.router.navigate(['/organisations/', +id]);
        return Observable.of(null);
      });
  }
}
```

Which I then refer to in the ngOnInit call...

ngOnInit() {

```
this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.returnCurrentUser();

this.route.data
  .subscribe(({aircrafts}) => {
    this.aircrafts = aircrafts;

    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(' where are my aircraft!' + JSON.stringify(aircrafts));
    this.ELEMENT_DATA = aircrafts;
    this.displayedColumns = ['Last Work', 'Rego', 'Make', 'Model', 'Contact', 'Phone'];
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    console.log(id);
    if (id) {
      this.organisationService.getById(id).subscribe(org => {
        this.organisation = org;
      });
    } else {
      console.log('its bad');
    }

  });

console.log(this.dataSource);
```

}

The console log under the subscribe is undefined and the console.logs under the service never get triggered. So once again, I find myself not understanding why subscription fire or not fire, or whatever it is that they do.

How do I get past this? thanks everyone.

**EDIT**: appears that the problem is actually in the ResolverService, I have been able to determine that the data service is getting the results and that they are correct. For some reason, the resolver service can't see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the route resolver, or rather the app-routing-module. I should have included it in the question, because some of the angular saltys would have picked it up

I was trying to do this:.

```
  { path: 'organisations/:orgId/aircrafts/:id', component: AircraftsComponent, resolve: {aircrafts : AircraftsResolverService}, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

But you can't, you have to do this:

```
  { path: 'organisations/aircrafts/:orgId/:id', component: AircraftsComponent, resolve: {aircrafts : AircraftsResolverService}, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

results in very non-resty urls, but, hey, whatever works, right?